# Forcing left to right order of cross section lines of river using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, profile, rivers, hec-ras

Based on "[Generating a series of cross sections (profiles) along a line?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232426/generating-a-series-of-cross-sections-profiles-along-a-line/321298#321298)" post, how can I force the cross-section lines to be created, thus collecting elevation data, from LEFT to RIGHT facing the downstream end of the river based on the example @StevenKay has provided?

I see that it depends on the CRS, but is there a way to actually force them?

I need to import the cross-sections of a river in HEC-RAS 2D and they need to be created specifically in such way from the beginning.

I am using QGIS 3.6.

Comment: I know there is a function in HEC-RAS 2D ver 5.0.7 -> Geometric Data -> GIS tools -> GIS cut lines -> Reverse cut lines which allows you to switch direction of all or some of the cross sections. But I was still wondering whether there is an integrated function in QGIS for time management purposes.

Comment: Yes, there is plugin to do so: Swap Vector Direction

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer your specific question, but I can help you to cope with the task.

I do not create cross sections automatically, but one by one, even then it is hard to keep the consistency and it is quite common the end with a couple of cross sections with the opposite direction.

Adjusting the cross section breakpoints to match the expected flow lines and avoiding intersections is already time consuming, so I think correcting the direction is a minor task compared with the whole process.

To find the wrong ones, the ones with the inverted direction, I just use the "arrow style" for the lines. Once I found them, I reverse the order with the plugin "Swap Vector Direction".

Comment: All I needed I think was that "Swap Vector Direction" plugin. Unfortunately, I cannot spend hours creating cross sections for rivers that are hundreds of km long. I'd much rather spend a bit more time creating a precise centreline and use the "Cross profile" function, and then re arrange the weird ones manually and then swap direction. Done ;)